# MySQL 8.0.33 - Simple Query Times Out - Possible MySQL Bug? (CONFIRMED BUG)

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization

**IMPORTANT UPDATE - MYSQL BUG CONFIRMED BY ORACLE**.
After being told by the MySQL bug support team that there was no problem and I was trying to get "free support", I stood my ground, told their team they were wrong in their analysis and formally asked for a manager (multiple times) to review the issue. Roughly one week later, a senior developer messaged me through the ticket and asked if I could send him a simplified database to reproduce the issue, so I did (basically, just the person_main and person_history_work tables). He was able to reproduce the problem and confirmed **THIS IS A BUG IN MYSQL**. He said the current workaround is to set optimizer_switch semijoin=OFF until they fix it. This bug has been in the engine since 8.0.11.

Link: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=111669

---

I'm scratching my head on this one. The below essentially times out on both my local machine and AWS. Here's the kicker, each subquery runs fine. The first subquery takes 55ms and returns 24000 records. The second takes 42ms and returns 4800 records.

I'm wondering if there's a server configuration issue I'm overlooking?

The person_main table is fully indexed as well, and only has 115,212 records.

Here's the query details:

```
-- This takes 20ms, 4800 records
SELECT phw.person_main_ref_id AS ID
FROM person_history_work phw
WHERE MATCH(phw.work_summary) AGAINST('finance');

-- This takes 20ms, 24000 records
SELECT phw.person_main_ref_id AS ID
FROM person_history_work phw
WHERE MATCH(phw.work_title) AGAINST('software');

-- This takes 700ms, returns 14000 records
SELECT pm.ID
FROM person_main pm      
WHERE
pm.ID IN  
(
    -- 49838 records
    SELECT phw.person_main_ref_id AS ID
    FROM person_history_work phw
    WHERE phw.ID < 50000
)
AND
pm.ID IN
(
    -- 299679 records
    SELECT phw.person_main_ref_id AS ID
    FROM person_history_work phw
    WHERE phw.ID > 10000
);

-- This times out at over 60000ms, should return at max 4800 records
SELECT pm.ID
FROM person_main pm      
WHERE
pm.ID IN  
(
    -- 4800 records
    SELECT phw.person_main_ref_id AS ID
    FROM person_history_work phw
    WHERE MATCH(phw.work_summary) AGAINST('finance')
)
AND
pm.ID IN
(
    -- 24000 records
    SELECT phw.person_main_ref_id AS ID
    FROM person_history_work phw
    WHERE MATCH(phw.work_title) AGAINST('software')
)
```

Now if I switch to LIKE for the above, it only takes 2000ms.

```
-- This times out at over 60000ms, should return at max 4800 records
SELECT pm.ID
FROM person_main pm      
WHERE
pm.ID IN  
(
    SELECT phw.person_main_ref_id AS ID
    FROM person_history_work phw
    WHERE phw.work_summary LIKE '%finance%'
)
AND
pm.ID IN
(
    SELECT phw.person_main_ref_id AS ID
    FROM person_history_work phw
    WHERE phw.work_title LIKE '%software%'
)
;
```

If I execute the query with just one of the subqueries it takes only 60ms.

The issue is if I use AND with either of them, it times out. The order doesn't matter. It makes absolutely no sense as it's only comparing IDs to being in the result sets.

If I change it to OR, the query completes in 800ms.

Here's the EXPLAIN:

[image]

Any ideas what's going on here?

===

Here's the create for person_main and person_history_work.

```
    CREATE TABLE `person_main` (
  `ID` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date_created` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT (now()),
  `date_updated` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT (now()) ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `name_first` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `name_middle` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `name_last` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `name_nick` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `name_full` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci GENERATED ALWAYS AS (trim(concat(if((`name_nick` is null),_utf8mb4'',concat(`name_nick`,_utf8mb4' ')),if((`name_first` is null),_utf8mb4'',concat(`name_first`,_utf8mb4' ')),if((`name_middle` is null),_utf8mb4'',concat(`name_middle`,_utf8mb4' ')),if((`name_last` is null),_utf8mb4'',`name_last`)))) STORED NOT NULL,
  `date_birth` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `department_type_gc` smallint DEFAULT NULL,
  `designation` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ID_UNIQUE` (`ID`),
  KEY `IDX_person_main_name_first` (`name_first`),
  KEY `IDX_person_main_name_middle` (`name_middle`),
  KEY `IDX_person_main_name_last` (`name_last`),
  KEY `IDX_person_main_name_nick` (`name_nick`),
  KEY `IDX_person_main_date_created` (`date_created`),
  KEY `IDX_person_main_date_updated` (`date_updated`),
  KEY `IDX_person_main_date_birth` (`date_birth`),
  KEY `IDX_person_main_department_type_gc` (`department_type_gc`),
  KEY `IDX_person_main_designation` (`designation`(128)),
  FULLTEXT KEY `IDX_person_main_name_full` (`name_full`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=177557 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci AVG_ROW_LENGTH=55

CREATE TABLE `person_history_work` (
  `ID` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `person_main_ref_id` int NOT NULL COMMENT 'Pointer back to people_main to define owner.',
  `internal_company_name` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `company_main_ref_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `work_title` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `work_title_scrubbed` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci GENERATED ALWAYS AS (regexp_replace(`work_title`,_utf8mb4'[^0-9A-Za-z]',_utf8mb4'')) STORED,
  `date_start` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_end` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `work_summary` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `person_email_ref_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `person_phone_ref_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `person_address_ref_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `compensation_main_ref_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `history_work_details` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `processed_sit` tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_person_history_work_ID` (`ID`),
  KEY `fk_people_main_id_idx` (`person_main_ref_id`),
  KEY `IDX_person_history_work_company_main_ref_id` (`company_main_ref_id`),
  KEY `IDX_person_history_work_date_start` (`date_start`),
  KEY `IDX_person_history_work_date_end` (`date_end`),
  KEY `FK_person_history_work_compensation_main_ref_id` (`compensation_main_ref_id`),
  KEY `FK_person_history_work_person_email_ref_id` (`person_email_ref_id`),
  KEY `FK_person_history_work_person_phone_ref_id` (`person_phone_ref_id`),
  KEY `IDX_person_history_work_work_title_scrubbed` (`work_title_scrubbed`(128)),
  KEY `IDX_person_history_work_processed_sit` (`processed_sit`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `IDX_person_history_work_work_summary` (`work_summary`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `IDX_person_history_work_internal_company_name` (`internal_company_name`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `IDX_person_history_work_work_title` (`work_title`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_person_history_work_compensation_main_ref_id` FOREIGN KEY (`compensation_main_ref_id`) REFERENCES `compensation_main` (`ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_person_history_work_person_email_ref_id` FOREIGN KEY (`person_email_ref_id`) REFERENCES `person_email` (`ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_person_history_work_person_phone_ref_id` FOREIGN KEY (`person_phone_ref_id`) REFERENCES `person_phone` (`ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_phw_person_main_id` FOREIGN KEY (`person_main_ref_id`) REFERENCES `person_main` (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=369407 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci AVG_ROW_LENGTH=81
```

Comment: please edit your question to show (as text, not images) output of `show create table person_main` and `show create table person_history_work` and explain (as text) for both subqueries and the full query

Comment: as a hack, you could do `WHERE (pm.ID IN (...)) + (pm.ID IN (...)) = 2`

Comment: @ysth Posted. Well, I want to understand exactly what's going on here as MySQL is not behaving as it should (from what I can tell). I don't believe there's anything logistically wrong with the SQL.

Comment: please don't show the create plus lots of alters you did, just show the output of `show create table yourtablename`

Comment: @ysth updated per your request.

Comment: Why does the IN condition of this query use the same predicate and table? I think you can first transform the in clause to make SQL more reasonable, and you can also try CTE. Finally, optimizing SQL requires more information, such as index information, not create table information.

Comment: @dogsCute because it's from a much larger collection of dynamic statements based on AND/OR/NOT selections - I just honed it down to these two and it made absolutely no sense it was killing the SQL server. I want to figure out what's going on. It really makes no sense.

Comment: I've updated the query details. Note trying to use CTE results in the same timeout. Something seems very wrong with the way the engine is handling things given the test of more records of a different query type is lightning fast using the same AND technique.

Comment: Updated ticket. Oracle confirmed bug.

Comment: @Floobinator - Please add a link to the bug in bugs.mysql.com so others can follow its progress.

Answer (score 1):

`IN ( SELECT )` has historically been inefficiently optimized; avoid it.

Your query starts with the large, unfiltered, table.  Let's rearrange things to start with the other table.

```
SELECT  phw1.person_main_ref_id AS ID
    FROM  person_history_work phw1
    JOIN  person_history_work phw2 USING(person_main_ref_id)
    WHERE  MATCH(phw1.work_summary) AGAINST('finance')
      AND  MATCH(phw2.work_title) AGAINST('software');
```

Better yet would be to combine the two FT indexes:

```
FULLTEXT 'both' (work_summary, work_title) 

SELECT  person_main_ref_id AS ID
    FROM  person_history_work
    WHERE  MATCH(pwork_summary, work_title)
         AGAINST('+finance +software' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

However, that may have a problem -- the keywords may show up in either column.  Consider whether this is a benefit or a drawback.  And think about workarounds.  If this is just the first of several filtering processes, this problem may not be serious.

Comment: Hey @Rick thanks for the feedback. The problem I'm dealing with is I have a system that generates Dynamic SQL based on front-end selections, so the program can create groups of AND/OR/NOT entries. This issue came up when I was trying to optimize it for speed - it currently uses CTEs but it's slower than it should be - in switching to inline SQL I found this "issue". Yes, that single query could be rewritten and work fine, but I need to find a solution that works with dynamically created "chunks". I was just surprised the "chunks" failed so terribly with the engine.

Comment: Updated ticket. Oracle confirmed bug.

Answer (score -1):

Your indices have no statistics. Try running [ANALYZE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/analyze-table.html) on the tables then run the query again.

And I would be rather surprised if you don't get a MASSIVE performance improvment if you use proper joins instead of IN (subquery).

Comment: Analyze came back OK. Given this happens both locally and AWS, I don't think that's it. When you say proper joins do you mean: SELECT pm.ID 
FROM person_main pm      
INNER JOIN person_history_work phw1 ON phw1.person_main_ref_id = pm.ID AND MATCH(phw1.work_summary) AGAINST('(.net sql) +finance' IN boolean MODE) AND MATCH(phw1.work_title) AGAINST('(software)' IN boolean MODE) ?

Comment: Also, what do you mean "Your indicies have no statistics"? I'm not following.

Comment: Sometimes (but rarely), `ANALYZE TABLE` will find that the statistics need updating.  The quick "OK" says that it did what it would do.

Comment: Ahhh understood; ran this and it came back OK and still the issue. I also updated and showed using LIKE %X% works fine, which makes no sense as the number of records returned is the exact same as MATCH.

Comment: Updated ticket. Oracle confirmed bug.